# How to use React Moment Use fromNow in element title?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am using the `react-moment` library and I am having a hard time figuring out how to set the title as follows.

```
<Moment
  title={<Moment>{createdAt}</Moment>} format="MMM DD, YYYY">{createdAt}</Moment>
```

## Output

`<time datetime="1389364532000">Jan 10, 2014</time>`

## Looking for?

`<time datetime="1389364532000" title="6 years ago">Jan 10, 2014</time>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with react-moment (it is not updated in the last 6 months -> red flag for any js library), and I am not sure why would you need it? 
The original moment.js which you can use by by `const moment = require("moment")` can do this just by doing

```html
<time datetime={moment().format("x")}, title={moment().fromNow()}>
    {moment().format('...whatever')}
</time>
```

Also I am not sure what does the [html time](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_time) tag `<time/>` has to offer above a normal div?

Comment: Thank you, that addresses the problem. I didn't know about its not have been updated since the last 6 months. Going away from react-moment. Thanks for the answer.